# Archive mails in shared mailbox prevent others to use Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that archives the T-1 emails from an shared mailbox.

The problem is that if I run the macro, all my colleagues will have Outlook frozen or will not send their emails until my macro doesn't stop.

Any help is welcomed.

```
Sub Archive_Outlook_eMails()
    Dim SourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MailItem As Object
    Dim SourceMailBoxName As String, DestMailBoxName As String
    Dim Source_Pst_Folder_Name As String, Dest_Pst_Folder_Name  As String
    Dim MailsCount As Double, NumberOfDays As Double
        Dim nam As String
        Dim dateYear As String
        Dim dateStr As String

    NumberOfDays = 0

    Source_Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"
    Set SourceFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - Office").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Copy")

    MailsCount = SourceFolder.Items.Count
    While MailsCount > 0

        Set MailItem = SourceFolder.Items.Item(MailsCount)

        On Error GoTo FFF

        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) > NumberOfDays Then

        dateStr = GetDate(MailItem.SentOn)
        dateStr = Format(dateStr, "mmmm")


        dateYear = GetDate(MailItem.SentOn)
        dateYear = Format(dateYear, "yyyy")


        nam = "Archive Office" & dateStr & " " & dateYear

        Set DestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(nam).Folders("Inbox").Folders("Copy")

            Dim myCopiedItem As Object
            Set myCopiedItem = MailItem.Copy
            myCopiedItem.Move DestFolder


        End If

FFF:
        Dim oTemp As Object
       If TypeName(oTemp) = "Outlook.ReportItem" Then
        Set oMessage = oTemp

        oMessage.Copy DestFolder
      End If


  Resume Next

        MailsCount = MailsCount - 1

    Wend

  Call send_email_for_finish

End Sub
```

Comment: add `DoEvents` after `While MailsCount > 0`

Comment: Why are you checking `NumberOfDays =0` if your archiving everything? skip that to speed-up your code.

Comment: I am archiving all t-2 emails

Answer (score 0):

I believe if others cannot work while the code is running it is an Outlook not a VBA issue.

You could ease the problem with better error handling so the code runs faster.

If there is an error the error handler does nothing and after several iterations the item is copied to the current DestFolder.

If there is no error the item runs through the error handler several times as well.

```
Sub Archive_Outlook_eMails_ErrorHandler_Demo()

    Dim SourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim MailItem As Object

    'Dim SourceMailBoxName As String, DestMailBoxName As String
    'Dim Source_Pst_Folder_Name As String, Dest_Pst_Folder_Name  As String

    Dim MailsCount As Double, NumberOfDays As Double

    Dim nam As String
    Dim dateYear As String
    Dim dateStr As String

    NumberOfDays = 0

    'Source_Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"

    Set SourceFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - Office").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Copy")

    MailsCount = SourceFolder.Items.count

    While MailsCount > 0

        Set MailItem = SourceFolder.Items.Item(MailsCount)

        On Error GoTo FFF

        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) > NumberOfDays Then

            dateStr = GetDate(MailItem.SentOn)
            dateStr = Format(dateStr, "mmmm")

            dateYear = GetDate(MailItem.SentOn)
            dateYear = Format(dateYear, "yyyy")

            nam = "Archive Office" & dateStr & " " & dateYear

            Set DestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(nam).Folders("Inbox").Folders("Copy")

            Dim myCopiedItem As Object
            Set myCopiedItem = MailItem.Copy
            myCopiedItem.Move DestFolder
            Debug.Print "Mailitem: " & MailsCount & " moved to DestFolder." & vbCr

        End If

        ' have to skip the error handling logic if you get here

FFF:
        Dim oTemp As Object
        Dim oMessage As Object

        If Err = 0 Then
            Debug.Print " ** Err = 0: Should have skipped this error handling logic. **"
        End If

        ' This code is not valid
        Debug.Print "TypeName(oTemp): " & TypeName(oTemp)
        If TypeName(oTemp) = "Outlook.ReportItem" Then
            Set oMessage = oTemp
            oMessage.Copy DestFolder
        Else
            Debug.Print " Mailitem: " & MailsCount & " Set oMessage = oTemp was not used" & vbCr
        End If

        Resume Next ' ?

        MailsCount = MailsCount - 1

    Wend

    'Call send_email_for_finish

    Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```

For this demo create a folder "CopyError" for the error items so they have somewhere to go.

```
Sub Archive_Outlook_eMails_ErrorHandlerFix_Demo()

    Dim SourceFolder As Folder
    Dim DestFolder As Folder
    Dim errorFolder As Folder

    Dim MailItem As Object
    Dim myCopiedItem As Object

    Dim MailsCount As Long
    Dim NumberOfDays As Long

    Dim nam As String
    Dim dateYear As String
    Dim dateStr As String

    NumberOfDays = 0

    Set SourceFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - Office").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Copy")

    Set errorFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - Office").Folders("Inbox").Folders("CopyError")

    MailsCount = SourceFolder.Items.count

    While MailsCount > 0

        Set MailItem = SourceFolder.Items.Item(MailsCount)

        On Error GoTo FFF

        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) > NumberOfDays Then

            dateStr = GetDate(MailItem.SentOn)
            dateStr = Format(dateStr, "mmmm")

            dateYear = GetDate(MailItem.SentOn)
            dateYear = Format(dateYear, "yyyy")

            nam = "Archive Office" & dateStr & " " & dateYear
            Set DestFolder = Session.Folders(nam).Folders("Inbox").Folders("Copy")

            Set myCopiedItem = MailItem.Copy
            myCopiedItem.Move DestFolder
            Debug.Print "Mailitem: " & MailsCount & " moved to DestFolder." & vbCr

        End If

returnFromErrorHandler:

        MailsCount = MailsCount - 1

    Wend

    'Call send_email_for_finish
    Debug.Print "Done"

ExitRoutine:
    Set MailItem = Nothing
    Exit Sub

FFF:

    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set myCopiedItem = MailItem.Copy
        myCopiedItem.Move errorFolder
        Debug.Print "Mailitem: " & MailsCount & " moved to errorFolder." & vbCr

    Else
        ' Should never get this now
        Debug.Print "Should have skipped this error handling logic."
        Debug.Print "Mailitem: " & MailsCount & " Set oMessage = oTemp was not used" & vbCr

    End If

    Resume returnFromErrorHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and answer but your code doesn't make the freezing less or gone (i have made counter), it still freezes like crazy.

Comment: Copying is a slow process. This behaviour cannot be fixed with better VBA. As a consolation fixing the error handling should lessen the processing time, even if only a miniscule amount.

Comment: If Outlook is freezing, you could try DoEvents inside the loop.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't do anything faster - from what i see.

Comment: DoEvents does not make processing faster. It normally makes the UI respond to mouse clicks (not freeze) when VBA is processing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you effectively need your code to run in the background so that the Outlook UI isn't locked until your processing is complete.  Unfortunately that is not possible as Outlook objects are not supported for use in background threads.  One option is to use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), which operates on the MAPI subsystem at a lower level than the Outlook Object Model and can be used in background threads.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the product on its web site? If you need assistance, contact the developer (Dmitry Streblechenko, a fine lad)